# Jsonを送受信するモック用APIサーバーを作成するには？

Tags: c#, json

UnityのC#でゲーム作成をしております。
Unityに実装されているJsonUtilityを使用した
Jsonの導通テストをしたいと考えています。

モック用APIサーバーの構築方法がわからず、
構築方法を探して回っている状況です。
（サーバーエンジニアさんの手を煩わせず簡単なテストぐらいはできるようにしたい）

■やりたい事
　クラスをシリアライズしHttpWebRequestを用いてサーバーへリクエスト
　↓
　リクエストで送信したものをそのままレスポンスに返してもらいデシリアライズする。

■環境
　Unity5.3.0f4
　Windows7 64bit

Comment: モックはUnityに限定せずC#でIISやWCFを使ってHTTPを処理したいということでしょうか。また「やりたい事」からするとリクエストの内容がテストと実運用で異なるように思えるのですが、仮にそうであるならWebサーバーである必要もあまりないのでは。

Comment: ＞C#でIISやWCFを使ってHTTPを処理したいということでしょうか
　はいそうです、ただUnityだとC#3.0までの機能しか使えないのであえてUnityと書きました。C#5.0の例を載せていただいても実際に動作させることができないからです。

Comment: ＞仮にそうであるならWebサーバーである必要もあまりないのでは
　そうですね、今回の目的としてはJsonUtilityを用いた導通テストを行なう事なのですが、自前でシリアライズしたデータを送ってデシリアライズして戻す環境を構築したいのですがわからないため投稿しました。

Answer (score 3):

`HttpListener`および`DataContractJsonSerializer`を使ってテスト用のJSONを返すサーバーを実装した例です。参照設定には「System」「System.Net」「System.Xml」「System.Runtime.Serialization」を追加してください。なお実行には管理者権限が必要です。

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var h = new HttpListener())
        {
            // TODO:リッスンするホスト名とポートを指定します。
            h.Prefixes.Add("http://*:58080/");
            h.Start();

            for (; ; )
            {
                var c = h.GetContext();

                var req = c.Request;

                // TODO:ここでURLを切り分けます
                Console.WriteLine(req.RawUrl);

                if (req.HasEntityBody)
                {
                    // TODO：ここでリクエストボディに対する処理を行います。
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(req.InputStream, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                }

                // JSONとして返したい値
                var value = new Result() { Value = true, Message = "あいうえおabcde" };

                // レスポンスにJSONを書き込みます。
                HttpListenerResponse res = null;
                try
                {
                    res = c.Response;
                    res.ContentType = "application/json";
                    new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Result)).WriteObject(res.OutputStream, value);
                }
                finally
                {
                    res.Close();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Result
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

上記のコードはUnityでは動かないような気がしますが、Visual Studioがない場合でもWindows 7に標準添付されているC#コンパイラを使えば

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe /out:C:\test\mock.exe /reference:system.net.dll /reference:system.xml.dll /reference:system.servicemodel.web.dll c:\test\mockhttplistener.cs

のようにコマンドプロンプトからコンパイルできると思います。コンパイルしてアプリを表示したうえで、`http://localhost:58080/`にアクセスすればブラウザにJSONが表示されるはずです。

Comment: JsonUtilityを使用できる形に改修してみます。